# I'm having trouble to convert a tuple to a string maintaining the parentheses

Tags: python

What I want to do is write the output:

```
Beate Adenauer, german, (hifi; phones), 11:12, 140
```

However the output I'm having with the code I have is:

```
Beate Adenauer, german, hifi; phones, 11:12, 140
```

What can I do differently?

```
    header='\n'.join(header)
    out_file=open(file_name,'w')
    out_file.write(str(header)+ '\n')
    out_file.write('Operators:'+'\n')
    for i in operators:
            domain = []
            for dom in i:
                    if type(dom)==tuple:
                            domain.append('; '.join(str(x) for x in dom))
                    else:
                            domain.append(str(dom))

            out_file.write(', '.join(domain))
            out_file.write('\n')
```

Comment: If you want the parentheses, use `domain.append(repr(dom))` on `tuple`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The join line in your code converts the tuple to a string.  This also drops the parenthesis.

```
domain.append('; '.join(str(x) for x in dom))
```

You can manually add in the parenthesis by formatting the string:

```
domain.append('({})'.format('; '.join(str(x) for x in dom)))
```